# How to export DB of a specific time?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I want to check how was my data 2 days ago and to do that I though of exporting a back up that Azure take every hour. But I cannot find it.

I've found [this page on Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export) that talks about exporting a DB but it is for the current data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure SQL Database [automatically creates database backups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-automated-backups) and writes them to read-access geo-redundant storage (RA-GRS) for geo-redundancy. Frequency depends on what kind of load the service is dealing with, duration backups are kept depends on the tier you've purchased.

To recover to a point in time using the Azure portal, open the page for your database and click Restore on the toolbar.

[image]

You cannot overwrite an existing database during restore, so you need to create a new instance for the point-in-time restore, and you'll pay for that. You can also do the restores programmatically using PowerShell.

Further details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-recovery-using-backups).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to execute a restore, with a specific time, on a temporary DB then export it to a bacpac file. You can use Azure CLI for that:
**az sql db restore** with -time option for restoring
**az sql db export** for exporting
**az sql db delete** for deleting the temporary database

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sql/db

The same can be also achieved using Azure Portal.